# Is there an interactive tutorial for Backbone that resembles the one for Knockout?

Tags: backbone.js, knockout.js

I've been evaluating JS libraries and frameworks for the company I contract for, and the best (for our needs—I'm not saying these are the best for every circumstance!) appears to be either Backbone or Knockout.  I lean towards the former<sup>1</sup> but I really like the interactive tutorial for Knockout, and think it would help drive acceptance among the other developers.

There are many tutorials for Backbone, but a big advantage I see of [the interactive Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) on the official Knockout site is that you just open the page and start playing with code immediately, and see results immediately, and it quickly becomes apparent that learning (at least the basics of) Knockout are not a big and formidable undertaking.  Suppose I have exactly 1 minute worth of attention of another developer to overcome the resistance to being told a particular JS library is easy to use and will save him lots of time.  The Knockout tutorial is a big winner when presenting to a *not-necessarily-motivated* developer.  With other tutorials you're still reading a description of what the library is and will do.  [You almost might as well hand them a 500-page WROX book and tell them to read it.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/25/Ain%27t_nobody_got_time_for_that_screengrab.jpg)

Where can I find something comparable to [the excellent Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro), but for Backbone?

---

<sup>1. Mostly because I'm already familiar with it, and the things which Knockout offers that Backbone doesn't can be easily added.  That might be true in reverse as well, but since I know less about Knockout it's not obvious to me if it is.</sup>

Comment: I think it's important the developers first understand what problems these frameworks solve. Either they will see the advantage of using framework X or not. I bet you could find some fiddle's around here that would serve as a good playground for backbone, while learning some of the common pit-falls.

Comment: The tutorial takes something closer to a *learn-by-doing* approach, which I believe is superior to *learn first and do later*.  I know they've all seen the kind of code that these libraries can fix.  My expectation is that once they see how KO or BB works, they'll "get it".  Any explanation of the problem to be fixed requires at least some proof that there's another better way, which I think the tutorials will provide.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [ChooseYourOwnApplication.com](http://ChooseYourOwnApplication.com)? It will allow you to walk through the same problem through any combination of Backbone/Knockout/JavaScript/CoffeeScript. It also includes options of different server side technology. One of the big advantages is that you see the strengths of the stack though the process of implementing the same web app. It does not include an interactive editor however.

Comment: It really looks cool, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the tip though.